# My python code stopping after first instance, how do I change this?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I wanted my code to read a csv line by line (large file) and then if the experiment ID is a specific number write that line to a csv. Only problem is it only writes the first instance then stops. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
out = open('new.csv', 'w')
with open('exp.csv','r') as w:
    header =w.readline()
    out.write(header)
    for line in w:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        tokens = line.split(",")
        exp_id = tokens[0]
        if (exp_id=='2243920414'): 
           out.write(line)
           continue
out.close()
```

Comment: The `continue` is redundant.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil `out.close()` is required. Otherwise the file will be corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove the `line = line.strip('\n')` and it works fine.
If you remove the newline, you just append all of the matching lines onto a single line which in your eyes looked like it had only matched once.

```
with open('exp.csv','r') as w, open('new.csv', 'w') as out:
    header = w.readline()
    out.write(header)
    for line in w:
        tokens = line.split(",")
        exp_id = tokens[0]
        if (exp_id=='2243920414'):
           out.write(line)
```

You should also check the [`csv module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).
It's a great module for everything related to csv files.

Comment: Thanks @Sevanteri! This worked. I forgot to tell you that when I was working on this, but never too late for appreciation. Thank you!